# how to prevent onPointerMove from responding to one click

Tags: flutter, dart

i have the following

```
 Listener(
     onPointerMove: (event){
    log.log('');
    },
```

`onPointerMove` respond to any touch .. how to make it avoid one simple click
on other word: i only want it to respond when i clearly move my finger

i tried the following

```
 onPointerMove: (event){


    if (event.delta.dx != 0 || event.delta.dy!=0) {
       isMove = true;
  }else{
      isMove = false;
   }
    
    
   },
```

But the sensitivity is bad and not accurate

The minimum finger movement I want is at least 1 cm to respond on it

Comment: You might consider changing to a wider movement vector than 1.

Comment: kindly Feel free to write the code

Comment: I don't know enough about dart/flutter to be the best assistance here